# am getting this error code as error_LINE_

Tags: php

> Notice: Use of undefined constant `_LINE_` - assumed `_LINE_` in C:\xampp\htdocs\quizzer\question.php on line 9
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''questions' WHERE question_number = 1' at line 1`_LINE_`

Comment: can anyone help me out?

Comment: Not without you showing your actual code.

Comment: PHP line's constant is `__LINE__` note the two underscores before and after

Comment: These are actually two errors: you have answers for the `use of undefined constant _LINE_` notice. To help you solve the `error in your SQL syntax` error, we need to see the rest of your query.

Comment: <?php include 'database.php'; ?>
  <?php
  $number = (int) $_GET['n'];

 
   $query = "SELECT * FROM 'questions' WHERE question_number = $number ";

   
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error_LINE_);

    $question = $result->fetch_assoc();
  ?>

Comment: To fix your SQL error, table and column names in MySQL should be wrapped in backticks instead of single quotes. Although "questions" isn't a reserved word in MySQL, so wrapping it is optional.

Comment: thanks guys, is working now after i had removed the quotes on the 'question'.

Comment: am getting another error in my code:   <form method="post" action="process.php">
     <ul class="choices">
      
      <?php while($row = $choices->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
       <li><input name="choice" type="radio" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" /><?php echo $row['text']; ?></li>
      <?php endwhile; ?>

Comment: this is the actual error is given me  <?php while($row = $choices->fetch_assoc()) : ?>

Answer (score 2):

You are using the [PHP Magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) incorrectly. It should be `__LINE__`, 2 underscores preceded and followed.